# Where to start with this protractor task?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automation, protractor, automated-tests

I've got an task to prepare but I'm new in protractor field. Could You help me?
Only info is "what will You do with this from a position of automation tester"

```
'use strict';
var constants = require('../../constants/other/constants.js');
var ContextMenuPage = require('../../page objects/base page/context_menu_page.js');
var functions = require('../../helper/functions.js');
var ClientScenariosPage = require('../../page objects/impairment analysis/client/scenarios_page.js');
var IADashboardPage = require('../../page objects/impairment analysis/ia_dashboard_page.js');
var BasePage = require('../../page objects/base page/base_page_object.js');
describe('Impairment analysis - dashboard', function () {
    var individualAssessment = new IndividualAssessment();
    var iaDashboardPage = new IADashboardPage();
    var basePage = new BasePage();
    var footer = basePage.getFooter();
    var clientScenariosPage = new ClientScenariosPage();

    it('should log in', function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        helper.login();
    });

    it('should change calcset', function () {
        browser.sleep(4000)
        var CalcSet = element(by.xpath('//div[@class="calcset"]/strong[@class="ng-binding"]'));
        CalcSet.click();
        var input = element(by.xpath("//input[@class='k-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-empty']"));
        input.clear();
        input.sendKeys('16080902');
        input.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
        footer.getCalcsetDialog().clickSetButton();
    });

    it('should go to individual assessment', function () {
        individualAssessment.getBasePage().clickContextMenu();
        contextMenu.clickImpairmentAnalysisTile();
        iaDashboardPage.clickIndividualAssesmentTile();
    });

    it('should go to scenarios screen and assign collaterals', function () {

        browser.sleep(5000);

        for (var id of ["127-1", "129-1", "128", "125-1"]) {
            var client = element(by.xpath("//div[@id='DashboardD1LISTTODO']/div[@class='k-grid-content k-auto-scrollable']/table[@class='k-selectable']/tbody/tr[@id='" + id + "']/td[@class='row-click'][2]/span[@class='link']"));
            client.click();
            clientScenariosPage.getBasePage().getCarousel().clickIndicatorByName('Scenarios');
            browser.sleep(2000);
            var coll_button = element(by.xpath("//trtd[5]/a[@title='Show collateral allocations']"));
            coll_button.click();
            check_and_click();
            browser.sleep(3000);
            var back = element(by.xpath("//div[@id='listClientCollModal']/div[@class='modal-dialog']/div[@class='modal-content']/div[@class='modal-body']/button[@class='close']"));
            back.click();
            individualAssessment.getBasePage().clickContextMenu();
            contextMenu.clickImpairmentAnalysisTile();
            iaDashboardPage.clickIndividualAssesmentTile();
            browser.sleep(5000);
        });
    });

    it('should log out', function () {
        helper.logout();
    });
});
```

Is this a tricky question? Should I ask about more details like page it will test, or just prepare some methods?
I look forward to hearing from you,
Tomek

Comment: Try something first, but please come back and ask a specific question if you are struggling.

Comment: @Hida The only thing I can do with it a I can run it. After run I've get:

`[16:46:22] E/launcher - Error: Error: Cannot find module '../../constants/other
constants.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Pro\spec.js:2:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)`

Comment: protractor is not able to find the `constants.js` file. Ensure the path to file is correct. you can check that using `require.resolve(path/to/module)`

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question? they are asking you to analyze the code?

Comment: @Martin Blaustein - Exactly, I have to analyze the code and give suggestions. Correct me if I'm wrong but that some 'then' should be added. I've also read about adding cucumber and Page Obj. What do You think

Answer (score 0):

So you should know how jasmine works and the page object pattern (http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html).

With that there is no need to know protractor to analyze what the test does, just try to imagine every action like find something -> click that -> assert it

Also you can say they are not testing an angular page (`browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;`)

That the helper object is never declared.

And I guess there are plenty more things to say about it.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it.